# Angluar modfifying localStorage data to add Roles

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jwt, authorization

I want to implement simple authentication and authorization in an Angular project. I want to store a **JWT token**, and the **logged in Users data**, including **Roles** in the Local Storage. A routing guard service would check if the currentUser in the localStorage has the Roles required for the given route.

My problem is that if the user modifies the localStorageData, he could do some things otherwise he couldn't do. I understand that he can't make any valid requests to the server, because the sent token wasn't modified.

What's the solution for this?

Example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-role-based-authorization-example

Instructions:

1. Login with: Username: **user** Paswword: **user**
2. Execute in
   console:`localStorage.setItem("currentUser",'{"id":2,"username":"user","firstName":"Normal","lastName":"User","role":"Admin","token":"fake-jwt-token.User"}')`
3. Refresh page

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent the client from doing whatever it wants with respect to itself. As long as your server is protected that's all you can do.